# Swift: How can the dictionary values be arranged based on each item's Levenshtein Distance number

Tags: swift, levenshtein-distance

I have a dictionary of products of this format

```
static var RawSearchDict = [String:Product]()
```

> key: "5f3f03271439a18028e8c0ba", value: App.Product(name: "LeapFrog Blues Clues and You! Magenta Learning Watch for Preschoolers",  productPrice: 14.84, productImageUrl: "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/f3c7354a-5e70-41ba-a03f-3e3f1507822b_1.5f1104bfcda0ce4a6b730d123f90cbb2.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff")

> key: "5f3f460d1439a18028e9fe9c", value: App.Product(name: "Blues Clues & You! Peek-A-Boo Magenta (10-inch feature plush)", productPrice: 24.84, productImageUrl: "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1e26fca6-c880-42e9-8a97-99d4a5198e80.15f4afeead4018d7aed12683ae29242b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff")

I want to use user entry to find the best match in a product dictionary, called RawSearchDict, so I thought of using Levenshetein Distance number to do some sort of matching and ranking. My thought was

1. Get each product description, which is the generatedString, in the RawSearchDict
2. Find the Levenshetein Distance number of the generatedString compare with user entry
3. Create a dictionary of products, called DisplayProductDict, that arranges the product so that the product string with the lowest Lev Dist number will come first and display first in my swiftui collection view.

I was able to figure out 1 and 2 but I haven't figured out a way to arrange the product in a dictionary based on the Lev Dist number. here's my code

levenshtein Dist function

```
func levenshteinDist(test: String, key: String) -> Int {
   let empty = Array<Int>(repeating:0, count: key.count)
   var last = [Int](0...key.count)

   for (i, testLetter) in test.enumerated() {
       var cur = [i + 1] + empty
       for (j, keyLetter) in key.enumerated() {
           cur[j + 1] = testLetter == keyLetter ? last[j] : min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j]) + 1
       }
       last = cur
   }
   return last.last!
 }
```

This gets the product data such as description and then calls the function above to get the Lev Dist number.

```
 func getProductData(){
    
    Global.displayProductArry = []
    var pIndexVsLevNum = [Int : Int]()
    for product0 in Global.RawSearchDict{
        let generatedString = product0.value.name.uppercased()
        let productIndex =  Array(Global.RawSearchDict.keys).index(of: product0.key)
        let relevanceNum = levenshteinDist(test: generatedString, key: self.userWordSearch)
        
        pIndexVsLevNum[productIndex!] = relevanceNum
                        
    }
    // sort the dictionary by value
    let sortedTwo = pIndexVsLevNum.sorted {
        return $0.value > $1.value
    }
    let dictLen = sortedTwo.count
   
    
    
  }
```

My SwiftUI collection view source its data from Global.displayProductArry. So I want the final product order to be arranged in displayProductArry. Best matches first.

How can I order the dictionary values based on the Levenshtein Distance number? or What is the best way to implement order in a dictionary or array?

Comment: What exactly is the challenge here? Just create a map of `[Poduct_or_ProductID : Levenshtein_Distance]` and sort by value. You seem to have every piece figured out already.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track with your sorted array. 
What object are you displaying in your SwiftUI View? 
You can not create a sorted dictionary as it will never guarantee a specific order if you simply iterate over it. Swift’s Dictionary type does not have a defined ordering.

Comment: I'm displaying Global.displayProductArry which contains Product Object that was listed in the beginning of the question.

Comment: And how / where is Global.displayProductArry being filled? getProductData just puts an empty array on it.

Comment: @mimo I want to fill Global.displayProductArry with the Levenshtein Distance ordered product. So after products in Global.RawSearchDict has been rearranged I want to add them to displayProductArry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pIndexVsLevNum` should also have the `key` of your original dict as `key` not the `index` of the entry. You always want to access a dictionary with a `key`.

You will end up with a dictionary with the original key and a value representing your sort criteria that you can now sort into your array

```
Global.displayProductArry = pIndexVsLevNum.sorted {
    return $0.value > $1.value
}
```

with that you can directly access your initial dict

```
for product in Global.displayProductArry {
    print (RawSearchDict[product.key])
}
```

something like:

```
func getProductData(){
    
  Global.displayProductArry = []
  var pIndexVsLevNum = [String : Int]()
  for product0 in Global.RawSearchDict{
      let generatedString = product0.value.name.uppercased()
      let productIndex = product0.key
      let relevanceNum = levenshteinDist(test: generatedString, key: self.userWordSearch)
        
      pIndexVsLevNum[productIndex!] = relevanceNum
                        
  }
  // sort the dictionary by value
  Global.displayProductArry = pIndexVsLevNum.sorted {
      return $0.value > $1.value
  }
  let dictLen = sortedTwo.count
       
}
```